# Ruby on Docker: determining which image I need

Tags: ruby, docker

I've got a Sinatra app and I want to start doing development and production in Docker.  Seeing blogs like this: https://blog.codeship.com/build-minimal-docker-container-ruby-apps/ which advocate using slimmed-down Alpine image.  I understand the value of having a smaller image, however in my research on this subject I can't find a clear explanation on exactly how to know whether I will need, now or in the future, the full docker ruby image? Do I start with Alpine for dev and prod, and then assume that if I later need the bigger image, I'll switch to that?  What would be an example of the kind of new requirement that could come up that would require the larger docker ruby image?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends of your project's dependencies and of your workflow with your project. And so far you're the only one knowing that here

You can still install some though during the building process later with a `Dockerfile`, like the **Ruby Package Manager (rpm)** (which would probably be already present in many images though) and some ruby packages that wouldn't necessarly be present even if you use a larger ruby base image (therefore, a larger image wouldn't help for these dependencies, you'd still have to install them).

Other services (like databases for instance) could (and should) easily be handled by other containers such as `mysql` and therefore wouldn't require to expand your ruby image.

That question is very broad, therefore it's difficult to give a very specific answer.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm now seeing this: http://blog.kontena.io/dockerizing-ruby-application/   which says:  "ruby:alpine is based on Alpine Linux. It’s the smallest ruby base image, but the main caveat is that it does use musl libc instead of glibc and friends, so certain software might run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements".  Which gives me more insight but still doesn't really answer the question of whether or not to start with Alpine.

Comment: I can't recall any projects I've worked on where a new feature required anything other than a gem install.  So if Alpine supports gem install, why would I need anything other than Alpine to start?

Comment: @David It really depends of what you need. And I can't tell it for you. :/

I'd suggest to try with alpine and to reconsider your base-image choice if you discover some absent requirements that can't be easily installed.

Comment: thanks @vmonteco.  Can anyone else site _any_  specific example of a sinatra app feature that could not be supported by the alpine image?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use alpine and see where it leads based upon the response.